# Relative error of equivalent resistance of resistors in parallel

Tags: electrical-resistance, error-analysis

I just saw a formula in my book for relative error in equivalent resistance of two resistors connected in parallel.

> $\frac{\Delta R}{R^2} = \frac{\Delta R_1}{R_1^2}+\frac{\Delta R_2}{R_2^2}$

How do I derive this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

$\frac{1}{R} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$ for paralllel resistors

Then apply [equation 4a from this reference](http://www.rit.edu/~w-uphysi/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html) to each side.  In other words, consider the right side as $f(R_1, R_2)$ and the left side as $f(R)$.

$\Delta f(R) = \Delta f(R_1, R_2)$

Comment: Does the R.H.S. evaluate to $-\frac{\Delta R_1}{R_1^2}-\frac{\Delta R_2}{R_2^2}$?
What would the LHS evalute to?

Comment: the vertical lines in equation 4a are absolute value, so you need to omit the negative signs. LHS yields LHS of equation from the book.

Comment: How would I solve the LHS?

Comment: derivative of (1/R) = $-1/R^2$; then take absoulte value and multiply by $\Delta R$

Comment: But isn't there a $\Delta z$ in the equation you linked to?

Comment: yes, solve for $\Delta z$ = uncertainty in left side of your equation, then solve for $\Delta z$ = uncertainty in right side of your equation, then state the two solutions equal each other

Comment: I see that this answers the question, but why would one use eqn 4a, rather than eqn. 4b?

Comment: @RobJeffries If the errors to be propagated are standard deviation errors, you would use 4b.  If they are average errors you would use 4a.

Comment: Its probably a culture thing - I don't understand what is meant by "average errors". The errors I quote (and read about) are 68.3% confidence intervals -so "standard deviation errors" I suppose.

Comment: @RobJeffries "average error" would mean the sum of the absolute values of the errors for each data point, divided by the number of data points.

Comment: @RobJeffries section 2c of the link in the answer goes through specific examples of calculating "average deviation" and "standard deviation".

Comment: Got it - I more normally(!) hear this quoted as the *mean absolute deviation*, but would never think that a quoted error bar was this unless explicitly told so.

Comment: Page was moved ...can someone provide a reference