# The least count of a stop watch is 0.1s. The time of 20 oscillations of the pendulum is found to be 20s. The percentage error in the time period is?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, error-analysis

I don't know how to start. 
L.C=0.1 s
n=20 
T=20 
then for 20 oscillation=20 seconds time period
for 20/20*1/10=0.1 time period
(1-0.1)/0.1*100=90% (wrong)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has my textbook given the incorrect equation for calculating uncertainty in multiplication?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332419/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the error in your measurement ("20 seconds") is 0.1 second ("the least count"), then you are measuring the time for 20 oscillations as 20.0 ±0.1 second, and the error is 1 part in 200 (0.1 in 20).

Because you are measuring 20 oscillations, the error of the stopwatch matters much less than it would if you measured just a single oscillation - in a sense you are dividing the error over 20 cycles, so it is as though the measurement of one cycle has an error of (0.1/20) sec/sec.

In reality, there will be errors in your starting and stopping the stopwatch, as well as in your ability to determine when the pendulum has complete a period (best done by seeing when the pendulum passes through zero... but that's probably not the point of this question).

Does that help?